# Querying services (vs pods) via variables on Prometheus-Grafana dashboards

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, promql

I am trying to create a variable for the grafana dashboard where I can select the services as a variable

This is required because the number of pods per service may vary and I want to give the user a list of (inference)services from which they can choose from

This is what I have tried for getting the pods:

```
label_values(kube_pod_info{namespace=~"$namespace"}, pod)
```

Thanks!